# Array in Pascal

Tags: arrays, pascal

The program is input the number of equipments rented and the cost paid. If equipment is damaged there's an additional cost. And data entered should be outputted on the screen.

When I enter 2 for damage equipment and it ask to enter the original  the program it stops; however result is executed when I input 1; but for the number of equipments it accepts 0 and when I'm prompted to enter the number of equipments return again it accepts another number; I can't seem to figure out the issue.

This is the entire program that I have written.

```
    Program Rental_info;

CONST
    Flaterate= 100000;
    Penalty= 0.05;

Var
    client_name, ID_number: array[1..1000] of string;
    Total_equiprented, equip_return,equipcondition: array [1..1000]of integer;
    Total_paid, Balance, Additional_cost, orig_cost:array[1..1000]of real;
    num_of_clients,option,x,y,G,s, B, A, Clientaddcost_count: integer;
    Total_amt_out,Total_amt_received,Total_add_cost:real;


   Begin
        num_of_clients:=0 ;
        x:=0;
        y:=0;
        s:=0;
        B:=0;
        A:=0;
        Total_amt_out:=0;
        Total_amt_received:=0;
        Total_add_cost:=0;
        For A:=1 to num_of_clients DO
            Begin
                    Total_equiprented[A]:=0;
                    Total_paid[A]:=0;
                    Balance[A]:=0;
                    Additional_cost[A]:=0;
                    Orig_cost[A]:=0;
             End;
option:=0;
while option<2 do
         begin
          Writeln('Do you wish to add a client?') ;
          Writeln('Enter 1 for yes and 2 for no');
          Readln(option);
          IF (option = 1) THEN
            Begin
               Writeln('****WELCOME TO SSC Agricultural Rental Enterprise Records****');
               Writeln('Please enter the total number of rental clients') ;
               Readln(num_of_clients) ;
                // For s:=1 to num_of_clients DO  writeln(s);

               For x:=1 to num_of_clients DO
                  Begin
                    Writeln('Please enter rental client name: ') ;
                    Readln(client_name[x]);
                    Writeln('Please enter client ID number: ');
                    Readln(ID_number[x]);
                    Writeln('Please enter the amount of equipment rented: ');
                    Readln(Total_equiprented[x]);                                      
                    While Total_equiprented[x]>5 Do
   begin
                            Writeln('Please enter a smaller amount of equipment rented, amount should be <5!');
                                Readln(Total_equiprented[x]);
                           End; 

                             Writeln('Please enter amount paid for rented equipment: ');
                             Readln(Total_paid[x]); 
                    end;        

            For y:=1 to num_of_clients DO
                    Begin
                         Balance[y]:= Flaterate-Total_paid[y]

                    End;
                 For s:=1 to num_of_clients DO 
                    Begin
                        Writeln('Please select overall condition of equipment: ');
                         Writeln('1-Good');
                           Writeln('2-Damage') ;
                        //Writeln('Type overall condition of the equipment');
                        Readln(equipcondition[s]);

                        Writeln('Please enter amount of equipment returned');
                        Readln(equip_return[s]);

                        If (equipcondition[s]=1) AND (equip_return[s]=Total_equiprented[s]) then
                           Begin
                                 Additional_cost[s]:=0;

                           End
                           else if (equipcondition[s]=2) AND (equip_return[s]=Total_equiprented[s]) then
                           Begin

                                 Writeln('Please enter the original cost for equipment');
                                 Readln(orig_cost[s]);
                                 //Writeln(orig_cost[s]);
                                 Additional_cost[s]:= orig_cost[s]*Penalty;
                           End;
                     End;
                   For B:=1 to num_of_clients DO
                      Begin
                           Total_amt_out:= Total_amt_out + Balance[B];
                           Total_amt_received:= Total_amt_received + Total_paid[B];
                           Total_add_cost:= Total_add_cost + Additional_cost[B];
                           While Total_add_cost>0 Do
                             Begin
                              Clientaddcost_count:= Clientaddcost_count + 1;
                            End;
                       End;
   For G:=1 to num_of_clients DO
      Begin

                             Writeln('The client(s) with oustanding balances is/are ', client_name[B]);
                           Writeln('The total number of client(s) who are required to pay additional charges is/are ', Clientaddcost_count);
                           Writeln('The total payment received for rental equipment is ', Total_amt_received:0:2);
                             Writeln('The total payment outstanding for rental equipment is ', Total_amt_out:0:2);
                             Writeln('Client total additional amount to be collected for damaged equipment is ', Total_add_cost:0:2);

       end;  

   end 
   else
   Begin
         Writeln ('****Thank you for contacting SSC AGRICULTURAL RENTAl ENTERPRISE, GOODBYE****');
         Writeln;
         Writeln;

         Writeln('Press <Enter> To Quit...');
         Readln;
   End;

 end;

End.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your program enters in infinite loop when `Total_add_cost` is non-zero here:

```
 While Total_add_cost>0 Do
      Begin
         Clientaddcost_count:= Clientaddcost_count + 1;
      End;
```

and you don't change `Total_add_cost` inside the loop to stop it ever.

Reconsider this logic.

Comment: Can you assist in what I could possible use there for the counter; because it works fine when  I enter 1 for condition of equipment; is just when I enter 2 thats the problem

Comment: You are in a loop (`For B := 1 to num_of_clients DO ...`) where you sum the totals of all clients, one total being `ClientAddCost_Count`. You want to increment that value if, and only if, the current client has an additional cost (`Additional_cost[B] > 0`). You should not use a `While`-loop at all, but instead an `If` statement that checks the `Additional_Cost[B]` and increments (with 1) the `ClientAddCost_Count if that cost is more than 0.

Comment: @TomBrunberg; thanks alot; I got it now but for the part  where I enter the number of items rented it is accepting 0 and then when it ask for it again and enter another number for example it still accepts it even thou it doesn't match with the first amount. How do I ensure it matches.

Comment: @Sue Are you surprised if I suggest to compare the second entry with the first and reject if bigger? Or if it has to match exactly, reject if the values differ.